# How to mock an object and it's properties in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec3

I have a controller action that I'm trying to test that downloads a file.

```
def download_file(url)
  response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI(url))
  if response.code == '200'
    return response.body
  end
end
```

In reading up on rspec I see that I can create a double of an object and stub it's methods.  But, I can't seem to figure out how to mock it's properties.  So for this test, how do I mock the response that is returned from the get_response call to have a code and body property?  I've tried this but it's not working.  Instead I'm getting back nil.

```
it 'calls Net::HTTP.get_response which returns a response' do
    @netresponse = double("response", {:body => 'this is a test', :code => 200})
    @url = 'http://www.google.com'
    allow(Net::HTTP).to receive(:get_response).and_return(@netresponse)
    return_value = controller.download_file(@url)
    expect(return_value).to eq('this is a test')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're stubbing `code` with an integer, but the implementation compares against a string.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that?;)  Thanks!